# Check if form exists on a page and hide it

Tags: php, forms, hide, exists

I am using osclass for a classifieds website. The theme has some widgets of which one is a search form. It is called into a header which exists on all pages. However, I would like to hide the search form only on this one page.

The form looks like this:

```
<form class="nocsrf navbar-left form-vertical" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" >
<div class="dropdown navbar-form js-menu-search-container">
…
…
</form>
```

How can I condition the form to show on all pages except on this one only: item-post.php?

I would greatly appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `style` tag just on that page that hides the search form.

Add the following to the page you want to hide the form on:

```
<style>
.dropdown.navbar-form.js-menu-search-container {
    display: none !important;
}
<style>
```

Comment: That did it! Sometimes a simple answer is in front of your nose but you dont see it. :-) I dont know what I was thinking. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.form-hide{
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
<?php
function need_hide_condition(){
      $pos = strpos( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "YourUrl");   //likes /test.php
      if( $pos!=false ) return true;
      else return false;
}
?>
<form class="nocsrf navbar-left form-vertical <?php if( need_hide_condition() ) echo 'form-hide';?>">
```

Comment: need_hide_condition?

I need to hide it completely if it exists. I am not sure I understood your answer... Forgive me, my php knowledge is limited...

Comment: I had changed the previous code a little bit. You could change the URL as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!